# Macbook Pro 16" refuses to connect via ethernet

Tags: network, wifi, ethernet

I have new machine from my company. It's a 16" Macbook Pro, running 10.15.6.
Before I had 13" MBP, also running Catalina.

The old machine connected perfectly via Ethernet on my home office network.

The new machine does not.

Same cable. Same USB-C ethernet adaptor.

In network prefs I see green light on and IP addresses acquired. But there is nothing coming in. Pinging sends out no packets. When clicking a URL it says "resolving host" and nothing happens.

This same machine connects 100% via ethernet at my company's office on their network.

I have tried different cables, different adaptors and recently even a different modem. But no success.

Any ideas?

Comment: You need to configure IPv4 IP address, router address, DNS servers etc. according to your home. the office configuration will not work at home.

Comment: I didn't have to do that for the older machine. So how would I do this?

Comment: https://www.howtogeek.com/howto/22161/how-to-set-up-a-static-ip-in-mac-os-x/ This might get you started.

Comment: I would also check if a proxy server has been set up.  My wife's machine had one when she brought it home and the academy support said nothing was wrong as it worked at school!